# Hide Detail Field Depending other variable in Access Report View (Not Print View)

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2007, show-hide

I have a tabbed control (TabCtl45) in the "Detail" section of my report that that has three tabs. (Page1, Page2, Page3). I only want to show one page depending on another variable known as Fee Type. If FeeType = 1, then Page1 tab shows. If FeeType = 2, then page Page2 tab shows... etc.

I was able to make this work in "Print View" with the OnFormat event; however, I want all my data in one easy flowing page like report view. **Not in separate pages like print view outputs.**

The code looked like this:

> If Me.FeeType = "1" Then
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page1").Visible = True
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page2").Visible = False
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page3").Visible = False
>
> ElseIf Me.FeeType = "2" Then
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page1").Visible = False
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page2").Visible = True
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page3").Visible = False
>
> ElseIf Me.FeeType = "3" Then
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page1").Visible = False
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page2").Visible = False
>
> Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page3").Visible = True
>
> End If

**How do you I get this code to work in report view from the "Detail" section of my report? There is no event that I can see working for this purpose in the properties "Detail" section.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Report View is rather limited, the section events (like `Detail.OnFormat`) simply don't run in this view. Only in Print/Print Preview.

The only thing you can do to format single records in Report View is Conditional Formatting, but that's no use to hide things.

---

On an unrelated note, you can simplify your code a lot by doing:

```
Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page1").Visible = (Me.FeeType = "1")
Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page2").Visible = (Me.FeeType = "2")
Me.TabCtl45.Pages("Page3").Visible = (Me.FeeType = "3")
```

Comment: Thanks Andre for the quick response! This is the first time I ever used StackOverFlow. Appreciate the advice. Is there anyway for the print preview view to work as a continuous page and not separate pages. My users are primarily only going to look at results in the database and not print the results out.

Comment: If any one was interested, I solved my issue by removing the tabs and just over lapping the data on my report ....making the values in the data > control source section as an IIF formula. Using that formula, if something did not meet criteria, it then became null and I enabled the can shrink property (which essentially hid that data set). The tab control was just not functional in the report view.

Comment: @RohitTalwar: Cool, thanks. I suggest you write that as an answer (perhaps with an example formula) and accept it, so (a) the question is marked solved and (b) it will be better visible for future readers than in a comment.